# How do I create a diamond-like shape better with arrays of Isometric PNGs

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a tile system with isometric blocks I've finally after a lot of trial and error got it working with this code,

```
function worldGen(){
var lvl = 100;
for (x=0; x<=50; x++){
    imageObj.src = "grass.png";
    square.n.push(imageObj);
    }
    //Corner Top
    console.log("Top Corner")
    for(x=1; x<=1; x++){
        for(y=0; y<=1; y++){
            for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            square.x[n] = (x*64+40*5-lvl);
            square.y[n] = (y*64+32*3);
            context.drawImage(square.n[n], square.y[y], square.x[x], 64, 64);
            console.log("Tile X: "+x+" | Tile Y: "+y+" - X Pos: "+square.x[x]+" | Y Pos: "+square.y[y]);
            }
        }
    }
    for(x=2; x<=2; x++){
        for(y=0; y<=2; y++){
            for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            square.x[n] = (x*64+40*4-lvl);
            square.y[n] = (y*64+32*2);
            context.drawImage(square.n[n], square.y[y], square.x[x], 64, 64);
            console.log("Tile X: "+x+" | Tile Y: "+y+" - X Pos: "+square.x[x]+" | Y Pos: "+square.y[y]);
            }
        }
    }
    for(x=3; x<=3; x++){
        for(y=0; y<=3; y++){
            for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            square.x[n] = (x*64+40*3-lvl);
            square.y[n] = (y*64+32*1);
            context.drawImage(square.n[n], square.y[y], square.x[x], 64, 64);
            console.log("Tile X: "+x+" | Tile Y: "+y+" - X Pos: "+square.x[x]+" | Y Pos: "+square.y[y]);
            }
        }
    }
    for(x=4; x<=4; x++){
        for(y=0; y<=4; y++){
            for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            square.x[n] = (x*64+40*2-lvl);
            square.y[n] = (y*64);
            context.drawImage(square.n[n], square.y[y], square.x[x], 64, 64);
            console.log("Tile X: "+x+" | Tile Y: "+y+" - X Pos: "+square.x[x]+" | Y Pos: "+square.y[y]);
            }
        }
    }
    for(x=5; x<=5; x++){
        for(y=0; y<=5; y++){
            for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            square.x[n] = (x*64+40-lvl);
            square.y[n] = (y*64-32);
            context.drawImage(square.n[n], square.y[y], square.x[x], 64, 64);
            console.log("Tile X: "+x+" | Tile Y: "+y+" - X Pos: "+square.x[x]+" | Y Pos: "+square.y[y]);
            }
        }
    }
    //Center
    console.log("Start Center Gen")
    for(z=0; z<=5; z++){
            for(x=6; x<=6; x++){
                for(y=0; y<=5; y++){
                    for(n=2; n<=50; n++){
                    square.x[x] = (x*64+(24*z)-lvl);
                    square.y[y] = (y*64+(32*z));
                    context.drawImage(square.n[n], square.y[y], square.x[x], 64, 64);
                    console.log("Tile X: "+x+" | Tile Y: "+y+" - X Pos: "+square.x[x]+" | Y Pos: "+square.y[y]);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    //Bottom Corner
        console.log("Start Bottom Corner")
        for(x=6; x<=6; x++){
        for(y=0; y<=4; y++){
            for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            square.x[n] = (x*64+44);
            square.y[n] = (y*64+32*6);
            context.drawImage(square.n[n], square.y[n], square.x[n], 64, 64);
            console.log("Tile X: "+x+" | Tile Y: "+y+" - X Pos: "+square.x[x]+" | Y Pos: "+square.y[y]);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("Start Bottom Corner")
    for(x=6; x<=6; x++){
        for(y=0; y<=4; y++){
            for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            square.x[n] = (x*64+44);
            square.y[n] = (y*64+32*6);
            context.drawImage(square.n[n], square.y[n], square.x[n], 64, 64);
            console.log("Tile X: "+x+" | Tile Y: "+y+" - X Pos: "+square.x[x]+" | Y Pos: "+square.y[y]);
            }
        }
    }
    for(x=7; x<=7; x++){
        for(y=0; y<=3; y++){
            for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            square.x[n] = (x*64+4);
            square.y[n] = (y*64+32*7);
            context.drawImage(square.n[n], square.y[n], square.x[n], 64, 64);
            console.log("Tile X: "+x+" | Tile Y: "+y+" - X Pos: "+square.x[x]+" | Y Pos: "+square.y[y]);
            }
        }
    }
    for(x=8; x<=8; x++){
        for(y=0; y<=2; y++){
            for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            square.x[n] = (x*64-36);
            square.y[n] = (y*64+32*8);
            context.drawImage(square.n[n], square.y[n], square.x[n], 64, 64);
            console.log("Tile X: "+x+" | Tile Y: "+y+" - X Pos: "+square.x[x]+" | Y Pos: "+square.y[y]);
            }
        }
    }
    for(x=9; x<=9; x++){
        for(y=0; y<=1; y++){
            for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            square.x[n] = (x*64-38*2);
            square.y[n] = (y*64+32*9);
            context.drawImage(square.n[n], square.y[n], square.x[n], 64, 64);
            console.log("Tile X: "+x+" | Tile Y: "+y+" - X Pos: "+square.x[x]+" | Y Pos: "+square.y[y]);
            }
        }
    }
    for(x=10; x<=10; x++){
        for(y=0; y<=0; y++){
            for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            square.x[n] = (x*64-39*3);
            square.y[n] = (y*64+32*10);
            context.drawImage(square.n[n], square.y[n], square.x[n], 64, 64);
            console.log("Tile X: "+x+" | Tile Y: "+y+" - X Pos: "+square.x[x]+" | Y Pos: "+square.y[y]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

but there is a list of things it isn't doing, it isn't allowing a change of size, it isn't actually a diamond, and it seems pretty clunky for what I think diamond generation would look like. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry, I should have been more clear with the title.

Comment: already did it is now more suitable for the forums

Comment: Andy I honestly didn't realize that existed this is were I go when I have some type of problem, I'll keep it in mind next time that it does, but your right this is more of a code review then help, so I'll be care full next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it's a huge chunck of code doing a lot of different things, in many nested loops. It's actually hard to reason about that code and come up with good ways to simplify it if it's hard to ponder about your problem.

A few hints of what you can in order to simplify your problem:

```
for(x=1; x<=1; x++){
    DoSomething();
}
```

You are creating a for loop so that the value of x is only assigned once. You can simplify that by getting rid of that for.

```
x = 1;
DoSomething();
```

Another thing, you should try replace repeated portions of code with function calls. It would make your code less verbose and easier to work with.

For example, your log message is the same for all of the loops. Try wrapping it in a function in order to make it less verbose.

```
function my_log(x, y, square){
    console.log("Tile X: "+x+" | Tile Y: "+y+" - X Pos: "+square.x[x]+" | Y Pos: "+square.y[y]);
}
```

Also, there seem to be two patterns of code inside the inner loops. If you wrap those around functions, it might be easier to ponder about that problem.

Take a look below:

```
function worldGen(){
    var lvl = 100;
    for (x=0; x<=50; x++){
        imageObj.src = "grass.png";
        square.n.push(imageObj);
    }

    function my_log(x, y, square){
        console.log("Tile X: "+x+" | Tile Y: "+y+" - X Pos: "+square.x[x]+" | Y Pos: "+square.y[y]);
    }

    function task(first, second, x, y, n, square){
        square.x[n] = first;
        square.y[n] = second;
        context.drawImage(square.n[n], square.y[y], square.x[x], 64, 64);
        my_log(x, y, square);
    }

    function task2(first, second, x, y, n, square){
        square.x[n] = first;
        square.y[n] = second;
        context.drawImage(square.n[n], square.y[n], square.x[n], 64, 64);
        my_log(x, y, square);
    }

    //Corner Top
    console.log("Top Corner")
    x=1;
    for(y=0; y<=1; y++){
        for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            task(x*64+40*5-lvl, y*64+32*3, x, y, square);
        }
    }

    x=2;
    for(y=0; y<=2; y++){
        for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            task(x*64+40*4-lvl, y*64+32*2, x, y, square);
        }
    }

    x=3;
    for(y=0; y<=3; y++){
        for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            task(x*64+40*3-lvl, y*64+32*1, x, y, square);
        }
    }

    x=4;
    for(y=0; y<=4; y++){
        for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            task(x*64+40*2-lvl, y*64, x, y, square);
        }
    }

    x=5;
    for(y=0; y<=5; y++){
        for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            task(x*64+40-lvl, y*64-32, x, y, square);
        }
    }

    //Center
    console.log("Start Center Gen")
    for(z=0; z<=5; z++){
        x=6;
        for(y=0; y<=5; y++){
            for(n=2; n<=50; n++){
                task(x*64+(24*z)-lvl, y*64+(32*z), x, y, square);
            }
        }

    }
    //Bottom Corner
    console.log("Start Bottom Corner")
    x=6;
    for(y=0; y<=4; y++){
        for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            task2(x*64+44, y*64+32*6, x, y, n, square);
        }
    }

    console.log("Start Bottom Corner")
    x=6;
    for(y=0; y<=4; y++){
        for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            task2(x*64+44, y*64+32*6, x, y, n, square);
        }
    }

    x=7;
    for(y=0; y<=3; y++){
        for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            task2(x*64+4, y*64+32*7, x, y, n, square);
        }
    }

    x=8;
    for(y=0; y<=2; y++){
        for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            task2(x*64-36, y*64+32*8, x, y, n, square);
        }
    }

    x=9;
    for(y=0; y<=1; y++){
        for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            task2(x*64-38*2, y*64+32*9, x, y, n, square);
        }
    }

    x=10;
    for(y=0; y<=0; y++){
        for(n=1; n<=50; n++){
            task2(x*64-39*3, y*64+32*10, x, y, n, square);
        }
    }

}
```

This version of code is a little shorter, because it tries to wrap repeated code in functions. However, there might still be better ways to improve it, but it requires a deeper knowledge of the specific domain of the problem.

So my suggestion for you is:

- Try to give meaningful names to those functions and the arguments. I sinserely didn't know how to name them.
- Try to figure out the pattern of the numbers and see if there is a way you can reduce the amount of loops that you are creating.
- Is there a way you could encapsulate some of these objects in order to simplify the logic?

Also, refactoring and logic abstraction should be an ongoing process. Next time, in order to avoid falling in a situation like this, try to work your abstractions while you are developing. It will make it easier to expand your code later on.

Comment: Thanks this is very informative, I made some pretty obvious mistakes, that I didn't realize. so its always help for to get some advise on that, I will also take your advise and try to redo the rectangle to a square by starting with a clear head. maybe I'll notice something I didn't before

Comment: So I took your advice and I was able to shorten the code by well a ton this is the code now

Answer (score 1):

@thalesmello

The code now

```
function worldGen(){
var lvl = 100;
for (x=0; x<=50; x++){
    imageObj.src = "grass.png";
    square.n.push(imageObj);
    }
 for(x=0; x<=6; x++){
    for(y=0; y<=x; y++){
        for(n=1; n<=25; n++){
            i= Math.floor(Math.random())
            square.x[n] = (x*64-(40*x)+158 - (48));
            square.y[n] = (y*64-(32*x)+250);
            drawDiamonds(n)
            }
        }
    }
 for(x=6; x>=0; x--){
    for(y=0; y<=x; y++){
        for(n=26; n<=50; n++){
            square.x[n] = (x*64-(40*(x+x+x/5)-400));
            square.y[n] = (y*64-(32*x)+250);
            drawDiamonds(n)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
function drawDiamonds(n){
context.drawImage(square.n[n], square.y[n], square.x[n], 64, 64);
cLogDiamonds()
}
function cLogDiamonds(){
console.log("Tile X: "+x+" | Tile Y: "+y+" - X Pos: "+square.x[x]+" | Y Pos: "+square.y[y]);
}
```

So a big thanks to you, seriously thank you. it generates awesomely now

Comment: Congratulations! Looks a lot better now.